# How to get exact events of scrolled to top and bottom in scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I tried many ways explained around here on stackoverflow.But i am still not able to perfectly get each of the events in scrollview.

What i intend to do is change text in an edittext (wrapped inside scrollview) when top or bottom is reached so that large files can be loaded.

```
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            View view = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
            int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));

            // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
            if (diff == 0) {
                if(index<texts.size()-1){
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0,0);
                    index++;
                    mInput.setText(texts.get(index));
                }
            }
                // do stuff similarly for top position reached
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this :

```
 @Override
 protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) { 

 if(view.getTop()==t){
    // reaches the top end
    }

 View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1); 
 int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()+view.getTop()));// Calculate the scrolldiff 
 if( diff <= 0 ){ 
    // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
     Log.d(ScrollTest.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached" );
         }
super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt); 
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works but not always.Behavior changes sometimes if fast scrolled .I believe i can utilize onOverScrolled method better here.Thanks

Comment: Yes you can try that. You are welcome and happy coding :)